Receiving extra rows in the result set
I have 2 tables in SQL Server, an ItemTable and a PropertyTable.
They are defined as follows:
ItemTable:



ItemName
ItemIsEnabled
ObjectName




Rule01
1
Object01


Rule02
1
Object01


Rule03
1
Object03



PropertyTable:



PropertyName
PropertyIsEnabled
ObjectName




Prop01
1
Object01


Prop02
1
Object02



There could be rows in ItemTable for an ObjectName that doesn't exist in the PropertyTable and vice versa.
I wrote a stored procedure that returns a pivoted result set based on the ObjectName passed in. For example, with 'Object01' passed in as parameter, the stored procedure should return something like this:



ObjectName
Rule01
Rule02
Prop01




Object01
1
1
1



But, I am getting rows for Object02 and Object03.
How do I get just the pivoted columns for passed in parameter. I think there is a where clause missing in my code.
Stored procedure code:
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';    
DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';   
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(ItemName) + ',' 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ItemName 
     FROM ItemTable 
     WHERE LOWER(ObjectName) = LOWER('Object01')  
     GROUP BY ItemName) AS tmp

SELECT @cols = SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols))

SELECT @cols1 = @cols1 + QUOTENAME(PropertyName) + ',' 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT PropertyName 
     FROM PropertyTable 
     WHERE LOWER(ObjectName) = LOWER('Object01') 
     GROUP BY PropertyName) AS tmp1

SELECT @cols1 = SUBSTRING(@cols1, 0, LEN(@cols1))

SET @query = '
SELECT * FROM 
(    
    SELECT  
        I.ItemName AS [Name]        
        ,V.ValueColumn 
        ,I.ObjectName AS [ObjectName]
    FROM ItemTable I
--tried adding a where clause here; isn't working
    
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            CAST(I.IsEnabled AS VARCHAR(50)) AS [ValueColumn]
    ) V

    UNION
    SELECT 
        P.PropertyName as [Name]
        ,V1.ValueColumn 
        ,P.ObjectName AS [ObjectName]
    FROM PropertyItem P
--tried adding a where clause here; isn't working   
    CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT          
            P.PropertyIsEnabled AS [ValueColumn]
    ) V1    
) src
PIVOT
(
    max(ValueColumn) for [Name] in (' + @cols + ', ' +  @cols1 + ')
) piv'


Not sure if you're familiar with sql server syntax, but WHERE must come after CROSS APPLY so you should adapt you query accordingly. Since you're using pivot, the addition of WHERE gets messy, because pivot rewrites the query internally, a solution is usually to wrap your main table into a subquery or CTE where you can add your WHERE-conditions and APPLIES as you wish and pivot on the otherside. Another solution is to stop using pivot operator and use conditional aggregation or just don't do this stuff in sql server until you get a bit more practice

Also not sure why the UNION, sounds like you need a LEFT JOIN but i could be wrong

@siggemannen: I am using the UNION operator because I want to get all the Items or Properties for a given ObjectName. For an objectname, there could be items or there could be properties.

Oh, i didn't see that both tables could be sources of items

The need for a dynamic pivot is normally the sign of an XY Problem, in my opinion. Generally you would be better™ doing the pivoting in your reporting layer, if you want a result set like this. Have the SQL later return a (more) normalised resultset.

See example



ItemName
ItemIsEnabled
ObjectName




Rule01
1
Object01


Rule02
1
Object01


Rule03
1
Object03


Rule04
1
Object05






PropertyName
PropertyIsEnabled
ObjectName




Prop01
1
Object01


Prop02
1
Object02


Prop02
1
Object04



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @SelObjName AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'Object01';

select @cols=string_agg(ItemName,',')
from(
select ObjectName,ItemName,ItemisEnabled
from ItemTable
where ObjectName=@selObjName
union 
select ObjectName,PropertyName,PropertyIsEnabled
from PropertyTable
where ObjectName=@selObjName
)t;
set @cols=coalesce(@cols,'noObject' );

set  @query='
select @ObjName as ObjectName,'+@cols+'
 from(select ObjectName,ItemName,ItemIsEnabled
     from ItemTable
     where ObjectName=@ObjName
     union all
     select ObjectName,PropertyName,PropertyIsEnabled
     from PropertyTable
     where ObjectName=@ObjName 
  )src1
Pivot (
   max(ItemIsEnabled) for Itemname in('+@cols+' )
)pvt1 '
;
execute sp_executeSQL @query, N'@ObjName varchar(30)',@ObjName=@SelObjName;




ObjectName
Prop01
Rule01
Rule02




Object01
1
1
1



fiddle
